# React Native app (Expo app) build succcessful crashes when installed and opened

Tags: android, react-native, performance, expo, eas

I created a small project using react native , I build the app and there were no errors the app was running smoothly in Expo Go . But when i installed the app on my phone its crashing. OS is giving a message that app keeps stopping.

here is github link of my code: https://github.com/abidzaheer1/citygreens.apk

I don't understant the problem and iam new in the app development. Please anyone help me

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do:

1. Open your crashing app at least three consecutive times, which eventually will prompt a different prompt which will show you a report of the app crash - Prompt will say “Your app keeps stopping” and should have an App info button.
2. And better yet, use Expo Development Builds instead of Expo Go to avoid noticing runtime failures only after the app was built. It basically runs the same as Expo Go with the added benefit that it behaves just like your production app would.
   [Here is a detailed tutorial on how to do it](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)

After you do these steps you’d be in a better position to understand what the error is like.

Often the errors that manifest in this way are because of missing/outdated dependencies.

Use ‘npx expo install —-fix’ which will automatically adjust dependencies for you.

Finally, I noticed that you have commented out GestureHandlerRootView, which sometimes is necessary for some components to work properly.

Edit: I just saw that you have some custom build apks script for bundling your app. I would recommend you to use ‘eas build’ instead as suggested in the expo documentation.

Let me know if these steps help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer help me a lot , it started showing me new errors on  expo start --dev-client .

Comment: There is a new problem now. previous problem was RNN screens after i fixed the problem and restarted the npx expo start --dev-client and open the app its showing white blank screen. and the console.log mssgs are printing but instead of screen it is showing white blank screen.

Comment: Hello there. If you haven't fixed it yet, in your repository I don't see a few components that my expo apps usually have. Bear in mind that I see you are using expo-router, but fundamentally this should not be different. 
Firstly, I don't see a component named "App.tsx" in the root of your repository. This is usually used by expo to render the entry point of your app. For this to happen in your package.json you should also add the line:   "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js".

Look for clues about how your app is getting loaded by expo. Check the documentation for the init method u used